# How to get pytest-django to only run tests for a single app

Tags: django, pytest

I was hoping that, by default, pytest-django would run the same tests that `./manage.py test` does. Instead it runs all the Django tests and basically every python file it finds.

Here's my `pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
python_files=*.py
norecursedirs = .*, CVS, _darcs, {arch}, *.egg, django, south
```

I'd love to be able to do something like `py.test main.tests.TestAccess' to run a single test case. Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

I attempted -k but, even with that option, I see many other files being run that I'm not interested in testing. Here's some output:

```
(vgmdash33-env)The-Judge:vgmdash joshuafialkoff$ py.test -k nothing_by_this_name
==================================== test session starts ====================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.3.5 -- py-1.4.26 -- pytest-2.6.4
plugins: bdd, django
collected 18 items / 19 errors 

========================================== ERRORS ===========================================
_____________________________ ERROR collecting temp_scripts.py ______________________________
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/_pytest/python.py:463: in _importtestmodule
    mod = self.fspath.pyimport(ensuresyspath=True)
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:641: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
E     File "/Users/joshuafialkoff/Documents/setaris/vgmdash/temp_scripts.py", line 10
E       wget --http-user='xxx.com\xxx' --http-password=xxxxxx http://xxx.xxx.com
E                                                                        ^
E   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
___________________________ ERROR collecting fabfile/__init__.py ____________________________
fabfile/__init__.py:1: in <module>
    from django_fabric_aws import *
E   ImportError: No module named 'django_fabric_aws'
_______________________ ERROR collecting fabfile/django_fabric_aws.py _______________________
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:629: in pyimport
    __import__(pkgpath.basename)
fabfile/__init__.py:1: in <module>
    from django_fabric_aws import *
E   ImportError: No module named 'django_fabric_aws'
_________________________ ERROR collecting fabfile/project_conf.py __________________________
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:629: in pyimport
    __import__(pkgpath.basename)
fabfile/__init__.py:1: in <module>
    from django_fabric_aws import *
E   ImportError: No module named 'django_fabric_aws'
_____________________________ ERROR collecting fabfile/tasks.py _____________________________
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:629: in pyimport
    __import__(pkgpath.basename)
fabfile/__init__.py:1: in <module>
    from django_fabric_aws import *
E   ImportError: No module named 'django_fabric_aws'
____________________ ERROR collecting fabfile/templates/gunicorn.conf.py ____________________
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:641: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
E   ImportError: No module named 'gunicorn.conf'
_____________________________ ERROR collecting vgmdash/urls.py ______________________________
vgmdash/urls.py:5: in <module>
    from django.contrib import admin
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py:4: in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.helpers import ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1565: in _find_and_load
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1532: in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ???
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:159: in load_module
    py.builtin.exec_(co, mod.__dict__)
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/helpers.py:4: in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.utils import (flatten_fieldsets, lookup_field,
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1565: in _find_and_load
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1532: in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ???
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:159: in load_module
    py.builtin.exec_(co, mod.__dict__)
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py:6: in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth import get_permission_codename
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py:9: in <module>
    from django.middleware.csrf import rotate_token
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1565: in _find_and_load
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1532: in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ???
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:159: in load_module
    py.builtin.exec_(co, mod.__dict__)
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py:14: in <module>
    from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1565: in _find_and_load
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1532: in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ???
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:159: in load_module
    py.builtin.exec_(co, mod.__dict__)
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/utils/cache.py:26: in <module>
    from django.core.cache import caches
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py:34: in <module>
    if DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS not in settings.CACHES:
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py:46: in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py:40: in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
E   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
___________________ ERROR collecting vgmdash/apps/activity/formatters.py ____________________
vgmdash/apps/activity/formatters.py:25: in <module>
    formatter.register(...)
E   TypeError: register() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'field_name' and 'format_func'
_____________________ ERROR collecting vgmdash/apps/activity/models.py ______________________
vgmdash/apps/activity/models.py:22: in <module>
    class Log(model_url_mixin_factory(), models.Model):
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py:286: in __new__
    new_class._meta.apps.register_model(new_class._meta.app_label, new_class)
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py:213: in register_model
    (model_name, app_label, app_models[model_name], model))
E   RuntimeError: Conflicting 'log' models in application 'activity': <class 'activity.models.Log'> and <class 'vgmdash.apps.activity.models.Log'>.
_____________________ ERROR collecting vgmdash/apps/authstats/models.py _____________________
vgmdash/apps/authstats/models.py:13: in <module>
    class UserStats(models.Model):
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py:286: in __new__
    new_class._meta.apps.register_model(new_class._meta.app_label, new_class)
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py:213: in register_model
    (model_name, app_label, app_models[model_name], model))
E   RuntimeError: Conflicting 'userstats' models in application 'authstats': <class 'authstats.models.UserStats'> and <class 'vgmdash.apps.authstats.models.UserStats'>.
_____________________ ERROR collecting vgmdash/apps/fileshare/models.py _____________________
vgmdash/apps/fileshare/models.py:14: in <module>
    class FileShare(models.Model):
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py:286: in __new__
    new_class._meta.apps.register_model(new_class._meta.app_label, new_class)
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py:213: in register_model
    (model_name, app_label, app_models[model_name], model))
E   RuntimeError: Conflicting 'fileshare' models in application 'fileshare': <class 'fileshare.models.FileShare'> and <class 'vgmdash.apps.fileshare.models.FileShare'>.
________________________ ERROR collecting vgmdash/apps/main/admin.py ________________________
vgmdash/apps/main/admin.py:4: in <module>
    admin.site.register(Transaction)
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py:84: in register
    raise AlreadyRegistered('The model %s is already registered' % model.__name__)
E   django.contrib.admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered: The model Transaction is already registered
_______________________ ERROR collecting vgmdash/apps/main/loggers.py _______________________
vgmdash/apps/main/loggers.py:12: in <module>
    class ClientDetail(LogDetail):
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py:286: in __new__
    new_class._meta.apps.register_model(new_class._meta.app_label, new_class)
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py:213: in register_model
    (model_name, app_label, app_models[model_name], model))
E   RuntimeError: Conflicting 'clientdetail' models in application 'main': <class 'main.loggers.ClientDetail'> and <class 'vgmdash.apps.main.loggers.ClientDetail'>.
_______________________ ERROR collecting vgmdash/apps/main/models.py ________________________
vgmdash/apps/main/models.py:44: in <module>
    class Manufacturer(model_url_mixin_factory(), models.Model):
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py:286: in __new__
    new_class._meta.apps.register_model(new_class._meta.app_label, new_class)
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py:213: in register_model
    (model_name, app_label, app_models[model_name], model))
E   RuntimeError: Conflicting 'manufacturer' models in application 'main': <class 'main.models.Manufacturer'> and <class 'vgmdash.apps.main.models.Manufacturer'>.
_________________ ERROR collecting vgmdash/apps/main/features/steps/auth.py _________________
vgmdash/apps/main/features/steps/auth.py:7: in <module>
    use_step_matcher(re)
E   NameError: name 're' is not defined
________________ ERROR collecting vgmdash/apps/main/features/steps/browse.py ________________
vgmdash/apps/main/features/steps/browse.py:1: in <module>
    @when('I run a (?P<import_type>.*) import using "(?P<fn>.*)"')
E   NameError: name 'when' is not defined
_______________ ERROR collecting vgmdash/apps/main/features/steps/objects.py ________________
vgmdash/apps/main/features/steps/objects.py:9: in <module>
    use_step_matcher(re)
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/behave/matchers.py:209: in use_step_matcher
    current_matcher = matcher_mapping[name]
E   KeyError: <module 're' from '/Users/joshuafialkoff/Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/re.py'>
______________________ ERROR collecting vgmdash/apps/myauth/models.py _______________________
vgmdash/apps/myauth/models.py:16: in <module>
    class User(model_url_mixin_factory(token_field='username'), UserBase):
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py:253: in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class(field.name, copy.deepcopy(field))
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py:300: in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py:2241: in contribute_to_class
    self.rel.through = create_many_to_many_intermediary_model(self, cls)
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py:1847: in create_many_to_many_intermediary_model
    to: models.ForeignKey(to_model, related_name='%s+' % name, db_tablespace=field.db_tablespace, db_constraint=field.rel.db_constraint)
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py:286: in __new__
    new_class._meta.apps.register_model(new_class._meta.app_label, new_class)
../../../Envs/vgmdash33-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py:213: in register_model
    (model_name, app_label, app_models[model_name], model))
E   RuntimeError: Conflicting 'user_groups' models in application 'myauth': <class 'myauth.models.User_groups'> and <class 'vgmdash.apps.myauth.models.User_groups'>.
______________ ERROR collecting vgmdash/apps/myauth/migrations/0001_initial.py ______________
vgmdash/apps/myauth/migrations/0001_initial.py:2: in <module>
    from south.utils import datetime_utils as datetime
E   ImportError: No module named 'south'
====================== 18 tests deselected by '-knothing_by_this_name' ======================
=================== 18 deselected, 2 warnings, 19 error in 10.19 seconds ====================
```

Comment: where do you put the tests? What is your directory structure ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I see more options

1) use the path

```
 py.test <path_to_my_app>
```

py.test will search for test only in that subdir

or

```
 py.test <path_to_file>::<test>
```

will execute only

2) decorate each test with a specific marker

```
@pytest.mark.app1
def test_bla_bla():
    ....
```

and run with

```
    py.test -m app1
```

3) use `-k` passing the test funnction name

Answer (score 1):

You can run a single test using the option [`-k`](http://pytest.org/latest/usage.html#specifying-tests-selecting-tests).

Comment: Thanks. I already tried that, but I still see a lot of files being tested that I'm not interested in. Please see the update to my question.

Comment: It's not testing anything in those files, it's just evaluating them to match the string you passed in. It turns out those files have syntax errors, which is why you see the errors you report.